# Gpo lockscreen issue

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, lock-screen, security-policy

For our organisation we are using lockscreen GPO's to control acces for the users. Most users have a period of 2 minutes before their screen locks, but there are some who require 4 minutes. The issue we have rightnow is that users that should have 4 minutes have their screens locked in 2 minutes.

Overview of our policies:
[image: The lock policies we have, the 600 sec doesn't work either.]

Content of the 120 second policy:
[image: How the 120 second one is build up]

Scope of the 120 second policy:
[image: Scope of the 120 seconds policy]

Content of the 240 second policy:
[image: Build up of the 240 second policy]

Scope of the 240 second policy:
[image: The scope of the 240 policy]

I've tried numerous things but am that skilled with GPO's, how can I resolve this?

Comment: You would have to either enforce the 240 second policy or give it a bigger weight/priority in some manner. Every user is an authenticated user so the 240 second value is likely overwritten. Look at the link order for the policies (Should be visible if you click your domain name).

Answer (score 0):

In GPO:

Enable ScreenSaver.

Enable Force a specific default lock screen and logon image(need to download .admx templates)

Enable and set Screen Server time out 240 seconds.

Have a try.